# Is it possible to disable compiler warning C4503?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, warnings, pragma, suppress-warnings

The following code does NOT suppress ANY C4503 compiler warnings, but it does suppress C4244 warnings.

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable:4503)
#pragma warning(disable:4244)

#include <map>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    class Field;
    typedef std::map<std::string, Field * > Screen;
    typedef std::map<std::string, Screen> WebApp;
    typedef std::map<std::string, WebApp> WebAppTest;
    typedef std::map<std::string, WebAppTest> Hello;
    Hello MyWAT; // The C4503 error is NOT suppressed

    int a;
    a = 5.0f; // The C4244 error is suppressed
}

#pragma warning(pop)
```

Please definitively explain why C4503 warnings are not suppressed. Note: it might be due to a  similar reason as referenced in [How can I work around warning C4505 in third party libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107844/how-can-i-work-around-warning-c4505-in-third-party-libraries).

See [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/442051/cannot-suppress-warning-in-template-function) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181175/disable-warnings-in-visual-studio-2008) for more relevant infornation.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Without some extra context where you are disabling the warning it's a bit hard to come up with a solution. My guess: You disable the warning around the code that instantiates the monster template, but you need to disable before the header where the template is defined is included.

Comment: @Xeo I have double checked and confirmed that this is not the issue.

Comment: You should think about resolving these warnings, as they can later lead to problems, e.g. when linking.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I interpret [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/074af4b6(v=vs.90).aspx) to mean that my name is entirely safe. Suppressing these warnings should not affect program correctness, however, since Microsoft explicitly states that _The correctness of the program, however, is unaffected by the truncated name._

Comment: @ChrisMorris: Older versions of msvc had much lower limits, and I had the "luck" to work with some of them. The symbols were just truncated, and depending on moonphase, this either caused duplicate definition errors on link time, or caused the compiler to chose the wrong symbol to link to. In the "best" case this would just mean that the wrong function was called...

Answer (score 3):

Not clear from the context, but maybe you have too many `#pragma` statements? MSDN says:

```
 The compiler only supports up to 56 #pragma warning statements in a compiland.
```

Comment: I have double checked and confirmed that this is not the issue.

Comment: Then I suggest that you provide a minimal example. If not, we have no chance but guessing, and this is not very satisfyingly.

Comment: My question has been edited to provide a runnable example of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Bit weird but you can disable this warning using your exact code just by removing the `#pragma warning(pop)`. I don't understand why though.

*I should say I'm on VS2010 C++ Express edition.*

Comment: I created a new CLR console app, replaced the contents of projectname.cpp with the above code, added `#include "stdafx.h"` and compiled, and it gave me loads of warnings. Then I commented the final `#pragma warning(pop)` and there were no warnings.

Comment: I could imagine that the phase that generates these warnings is later, after all kinds of instantiations and semantics stuff, where the pop already is active.

Comment: @demoncodemonkey My question is why does the pragma pop need to be commented out?

Comment: @PlasmaHH This is what I imagine as well (this is referenced in my question). Does anyone have hard proof from Microsoft of this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe stating the obvious but you can use the IDE settings to remove this (and other) warning(s) entirely, as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715718.aspx).

That was the only solution that worked for me, and was justified after learning that Boost has warning enable/disable policies built within, which alter the behavior of #pragma push/pop/enable/disable statements.

Comment: This also works to disable the warning text in the output window.