# Where do I put #pragma warning(disable : 4503) for it to work?

Tags: c++, warnings, pragma, visual-studio-2015

I have a .h file defining a class. That class has a member which is a map nested in a map nested in a map etc.

```
std::map<ItemWieldMode,
    std::map<AgentType::HandState,
         std::map<AgentType::MovementState,
               std::map<AgentType::BodyState, 
                   std::map<Vec2<int>, sp<AnimationEntry>>>>>> standart_animations;
```

This is the file in question https://github.com/Istrebitel/OpenApoc/blob/master/game/state/battle/battleunitanimationpack.h

Naturally, a C4503 warning pops, name too long and was truncated.

I am trying to suppress it. No matter where I put "#pragma warning(disable : 4503)" it doesn't work. I tried in the beginning of the .h file, in the beginning of the .cpp file using this class - nothing works. Compiler still gives warning.

I'm using VS 2015 community.

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/898267/not-able-to-suppress-warning-4503-decorated-name-length-exceeded-name-was-truncated

Comment: @HansPassant oh lol, so they won't even bother fixing it? Typical M$...

Comment: C4503 appears to be difficult to disable if you have `#pragma warning(pop)` afterwards. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673504/is-it-possible-to-disable-compiler-warning-c4503

Answer (score 0):

If you put `#pragma warning(disable : 4503)` **after** the `push` you get the warning. If you put it **before**, there are **no warnings**. That means the code above generates `C4503 warnings`, even though it was `disabled`.

For example,

```
#pragma warning (disable:4503)
#pragma warning (push, 1)

.
.
.
.

#pragma warning (pop)
```

Reference link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I tried putting this at the beginning and the end of the .h file and warnings still happen

Answer (score 0):

For others who may need it since I'm sure you figured it out by now:

The #pragma line simply goes right before the line with the warning you are trying to suppress.